# $_SESSION not being able to read value between php pages using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got a problem with passing data between 2 PHP files using a simple Javascript.

In events.php I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#row").load("includes/getRecords.inc.php" + window.location.search); 
   $(".paging_link").bootpag({
      total: <?php echo $_SESSION['pages']; ?>
   }).on("page", function(e, num){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#row").load("includes/getRecords.inc.php" + window.location.search, {'page':num});

   });
});
</script>
```

While on getRecords.php, I got:

```
$_SESSION['pages'] = $test;
```

$_SESSION['pages'] in **events.php** is not showing anything even when tested with print_r. Why is the session value not being read from **getRecords.php** when the method .load is called?

Thanks

Comment: *The $64,000 question:* - "Did you start the session?"

Comment: Yes, it is being called by using require("conn.inc.php"); which contains session_start().

Comment: every php no mater which one has to have it's own session_start()

Comment: I have to disagree. This method works perfectly with other pages. I believe the problem is when the code $("#row").load("includes/getRecords.inc.php" + window.location.search); is being executed. The .load is an ajax method.

Comment: @LaithHadi I think you want to `<?php include "includes/getRecords.inc.php"; ?>` or something.

Comment: @Winestone I don't see how this will help fix the error? I've used require to ensure that if the database connection fails, a fatal error occurs. Thanks for the suggestion though.